# Rank correlation not equal correlation on ranks in cor()

Tags: r, spearman-rho, correlation

Why am I getting different results for Pearson and Spearman correlation, although I am already comparing ranks?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,2,1,2,3)
cor(a, b, method="pearson")
# [1] 0.8911328
cor(a, b, method="spearman")
# [1] 0.9036961
```

Formula to use when there are tied ranks seems identical to formula for pearson correlation.

- [Spearman correlation](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide.php) (at the very bottom)
- [Pearson
  correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)

As far as I understand, spearman correlation is just pearson correlation on the ranks. Right?

---

[R function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/cor)

Comment: your inputs are not ranks in the usual meaning of the term?

Comment: What would be the corresponding ranks if they are not?

Comment: Try cor(rank(a), rank(b), method = ...)

Comment: Consider the data in `a` as if it represented positions in a race among six people: two people tied for each position.  There are various ways to assign ranks with ties, but typically the ranks that would be given to the top two places--namely 1 and 2--would be averaged, giving a rank of 1.5 to the first two finishers.  Similarly, the next two would have equal ranks of 3.5 and the last two would have ranks of 5.5.

Comment: thanks, i tried it with the rank function and I saw how R assigns ranks differently from what I expected.

Comment: @mdewey would you like to post this as an answer? Or should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @mdewey I am not already using ranks. If I use the correct ranks results are identical as expected.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,3)
b <- c(1,2,2,1)
cor(a, b, method="spearman")
# [1] 0.2357023
rank(a)
# [1] 1.0 2.0 3.5 3.5
rank(b)
# [1] 1.5 3.5 3.5 1.5
cor(rank(a), rank(b), method="spearman")
# [1] 0.2357023
```